# Testing SOQL Calls in Custom Controller

Tags: soql, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm trying to write a test class for a custom controller that only has some variable definitions and SOQL calls.  I've never written a test class for a SOQL call before and honestly have no idea where to start, and nothing I've googled has been clear or understandable to me.

Here's my controller:

```
public class TicketTestCon {


public Ticket__c[] tickets{ get; set; }
public Availability_Schedule__c[] availabilities{ get; set; }
public Payment__c[] payments{ get; set; }
private List<Contact> contacts{ get; set; }
public List<User> users { get; set; }
private List<User> currentUser { get; set; }
public String userID { get; set; }

//Constructor
public TicketTestCon(){

    users = [SELECT External_Customer_ID__c FROM User];
    contacts = [SELECT ExternalCID__c FROM Contact];
    currentUser = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Name = :UserInfo.getName()];
    userID = Userinfo.getUserId();
    tickets = [SELECT Name,Location__c,PriceType__c,Date_Time__c,Contact__c,ExperienceSchedule__c,Guide__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Guide__c = :currentUser ORDER BY Name ];
    availabilities = [SELECT Name,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c,Start_Time__c,End_Time__c,Duration__c FROM Availability_Schedule__c WHERE Guide__c = :currentUser ];
    payments = [SELECT Name,Amount__c FROM Payment__c ];

    } 
}
```

And here's my test class (really, a test class frame, which is obviously wrong):

```
@isTest
private class TicketTestTestClass {

static testMethod void test1(){
    Ticket__c[] tickets;        
    tickets = [SELECT Name,Location__c,PriceType__c,Date_Time__c,Contact__c,ExperienceSchedule__c,Guide__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Guide__c = null ORDER BY Name ];
    }   
}
```

What exactly do I write to test this?? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create test data in your test class that meets the criteria for your query, including any related records that you might be querying. I recommend you create lists of records to insert so you won't be returning a single result. Use iterators to add variation in names, addresses, etc when you create your data.

Beyond that, you need to instantiate a new page reference and then an instance of your class. Set any values that you need just like you would in a regular visualforce controller test page. See the Trailhead module on Visualforce or the [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/) for more.